# Как правильно писать: "уважаемый(ая)" или "уважаемый(-ая)" с тире перед окончанием?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: "уважаемый(ая)" или "уважаемый(-ая)" с тире перед окончанием?

Answer (score 2):

*Уважаемый (ая)* — с пробелом перед скобками, без дефиса.

Answer (score 0):

Такое лучше вообще не писать.

Во-первых, нигде подобные упражнения не регламентированы.
Ну а во-вторых, уважаемый - выражение уважения хоть сколько-то известному лицу. Как вы себе представляете уважение того, чья гендерная принадлежность вам неизвестна? Это что спамовая рассылка от общества анонимных трасвеститов?

Впрочем я одно могу сказать, оснований для тире/дефиса я тут не вижу никаких. Так что если уж писать, то без него. Насчет пробела, о котором написала Завада, ничего не могу сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Русский язык консервативен в гендерных проблемах (и не только в них). Он с трудом переваривает англоязычное требование gender neutral (гендерная нейтральность), и не очень спешит под него подстраиваться. Поэтому, в русском языке сохраняется использование мужского рода по дефолту и к мужчинам, и к женщинам, как это раньше было во всех языках. Например, "программист решает эту задачу в соответствии с принятыми ...". В данном случае "программист" может означать и мужчину, и женщину. Как правило, не пишут программист(ка).

Поэтому в России сохраняется несколько осторожное отношение к оборотам типа "Уважаемый(ая)" и их стоит употреблять только когда нет никакой возможности узнать пол адресата и нет никакого другого выхода.

Comment: Да, стоит избегать, тем более что за определением "уважаемый" всегда следует существительное, и его род тоже придется  варьировать, если уж стали на этот путь.